# How do I sync visuals to one slicer in Power BI Online?

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have a 1 page report that I need to split into 2 pages. It currently has one slicer in the top left that controls all visuals.

In Power BI desktop I could just sync the visuals to the 1 slicer. How do I do this in the online version?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sync slicers in both Desktop and online, from the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers#sync-and-use-slicers-on-other-pages), open the report and select the view item to turn on the sync slicers option. You can now sync/de-sync your items as required like the desktop version

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!! I was looking all over for the sync slicer option but couldn't find it. Your help is much appreciated.